# how to check a parameter is null or empty in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, isnull

How can I check if a parameter is null or empty in a stored procedure in mysql?
In other words what is equivalent of `ISNULL`in mysql ?
I tried `IFNULL` and `IS NULL`but they didn't work.

What I want is, to check if a parameter of stored procedure is null or empty then procedure raises an error and doesn't insert new record into table.

Comment: Did you try == NULL ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_nmae IS NULL

Comment: Please post your stored procedure as well, so that question become clear to others.

Comment: @Abbas Anyone proficient in SQL should know that you can't use `=` with `NULL`, you have to use `IS NULL`.

Comment: The equivalent of `ISNULL` is `ISNULL`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
IF(NAME_OF_THE_VAR IS NULL) THEN  
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Order No not found in orders table'; 
END IF;
```